How to center a CustomTkinter App on the screen?
The way I get it, scaling is dpi aware in customtkinter, but positioning is not?
It seems I need to set x_pos and y_pos regarding x+<x_pos>+<y_pos> in physical pixels (retrieved with e.g. ctypes).
But I would really like to know the conversion that ctk does when being set to scale dpi aware (default).
I tried:
dpi_scaling = self.tk.call('tk', 'scaling')
But this gave me a value of 1.33.. something instead of 1.25, with my display being set to 125%.
So is there a way to get the actual conversion factor?
Or is there a more straightforward way to center the app on the screen?
Best Regards

Your solution doesn't work because tkinter does not support scaling and you are calling a tkinter function and not a customtkinter.
To get the scaling used by customtkinter you can use something like this:
import customtkinter as ctk

win = ctk.CTk()

scaling = ctk.ScalingTracker().get_window_scaling(win)
print(scaling)

win.mainloop()

To center your window you can do this:
import customtkinter as ctk


win = ctk.CTk()

scaling = ctk.ScalingTracker().get_window_scaling(win)
width = win.winfo_screenwidth()
height = win.winfo_screenheight()

win.geometry(f"300x300+{int(width/2*scaling)}+{int(height/2*scaling)}")

win.mainloop()

This will center the top left corner of the window in the middle of the screen.
Hope I helped you, have a nice day
